# checking for the uniqueness of a value using jquery validation

Tags: java, jquery, spring, validation

I am trying to check whether the input value already exists in the database and let the user know about it using [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/form-validation/jquery-form-validation-guide.phtml) Jquery validator.

it has a example for checking the uniqueness of a input value [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/form-validation/jquery-form-validation-guide.phtml#remote_validation).

In my case I use `Java` with `Spring MVC`.

**This is how I do it.**

*In my `jsp` page*

```
var agrmntNo = jQuery('#agreementNo').val();

    $("#myform").validate(
    {
        rules: 
        {
             agreementNo: 
            {
                required: true,
               remote:'/TFProject/check_agreementNo'+agrmntNo+'.htm'
            }
        },
        messages: 
        {
            agreementNo: 
            {
                required: "Please enter.",
                remote:"This agreement number has already been used !."
            }
        }
    });
```

*This is the `Java` method I use.*

```
@RequestMapping(value="/check_agreementNo1{agrmntNo}.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public boolean check_agreementNo (@PathVariable("agrmntNo") String agrmntNo){


            System.out.println("DEBUG:Inside check agreement No in PMS Controller");
            System.out.println("DEBUG: URL parameter is : "+agrmntNo);

            AgreementBean agrbn = new AgreementBean();

            agrbn.setAgrmntNo(agrmntNo);

            String rslt = customerservice.check_agreementNo(agrbn);

            if(Integer.parseInt(rslt) > 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }
```

In this case, it gets into the `Java` method. But the parameter is not get passed. Once I submit my form, I can see this in my browser console.

```
GET http://localhost:8081/TFProject/check_agreementNo1.htm?agreementNo=54 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

it seems it does not recognize the way(the way in `spring`) parameter is passed.
What Can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The validation library clearly passes the value as a query parameter. You can't add a value to the remote parameter like you're doing.

The most sensible thing to do is to change your Java method to accept a request parameter instead of a path variable. Your scheme is bad and confusing anyway, because "/check_agreementNo1{agrmntNo}.htm" doesn't correspond to REST or any other sensible standard.